# Error:Initialization error (typescript). Cannot read property 'getExecutingFilePath' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea

I configured a new Angular2 type application through npm.
I am able to run it from node command prompt through `ng serve`.
But in IntelliJ IDEA(2016.3.4), I can't run from console. Its showing error:

> Error:Initialization error (typescript). Cannot read property
>   'getExecutingFilePath' of undefined

[image]

Comment: it seems your local project tsc and global are different version, check both versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please make sure to set **Typescript version** in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript** to *Bundled*; Typescript 2.6+ can't be used with IDEA 2016.x due to breaking API changes

[image]

If you like to use recent TypeScript versions, you have to upgrade IDEA to 2018.x

Comment: this isn't resolving the problem for me, and I have same error, in a new angular 7 project